# Understanding NTP Reach Metric -- What constitutes a failed NTP transaction?

Tags: linux, ntp

I'm currently troubleshooting an NTP (v4.6.2 for clients) syncing issue with all of my systems on a specific LAN. They're on a network I do not own, nor have a view into what the network architecture looks like, and syncing with an NTP reference server (that I also do not own) on that LAN. I can't run active commands on these machines. I have to request someone else run a command to remotely do something to these machines and then get logs ~24 hours later. What I've done in lieu of a packet capture is setup an hourly cronjob of `ntpq -pn` to tell me what (if any) NTP server these devices are listening to, what the jitter and reach are. The reach on all these devices (there are 5 of them) is bouncing all over the place, the jitter is also extremely high frequently (though not always), sometimes making it as high as 10000 or more.

**My main question is about the reach metric and how it calculates failed/successful transactions.** I understand that the [reach metric](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6812) is an octal value representation of the last 8 NTP transactions binary status (0 failed, 1 successful). I just can't seem to find anywhere that describes exactly what constitutes a failed NTP transaction. Obviously dropped NTP packets would constitute a failed transaction but is there anything else? Would discarding a packet because jitter is too high or the time difference is outside of the panic threshold constitute a failed transaction? Can anyone point me to documentation that *actually* shows what an NTP failed transaction is?

I feel like a packet capture would make it immediately obvious to me whether or not these failed transactions are dropped packets but as that's not available to me I really don't have much to go on other than an hourly cronjob output of `ntpq -pn` For reference, the output of some of these cronjobs is below with IP/RefID info scrubbed. Note than after a reboot (these systems have no internal battery and lose their clocks on a reboot) we often see NTP failing to sync and no * by the LAN NTP server or it's local address. So far *all devices* show the exact same reach values when failing to sync suggesting that this is an issue with some common network device preventing them from talking to the NTP reference or the NTP reference server itself not responding during these times. To further reinforce this, when these devices reboot, they always sync at roughly the same time (within seconds of each other).

Could anyone point me to what constitutes a failed NTP transaction or, barring that, have any insight into what the reach/jitter values suggests?

```
Sep 19 23:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
Sep 19 23:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: ==============================================================================
Sep 19 23:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: *127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          14 l   14   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.031
Sep 19 23:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:  LAN NTP       NTP REFERENCE IP  2 u   66   64  377    0.453  2159.21 544.980
--
Sep 20 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
Sep 20 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: ==============================================================================
Sep 20 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: *127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          14 l   30   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.031
Sep 20 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: LAN NTP       NTP REFERENCE IP    2 u    6   64  377    0.482  1595.79 320.179
--
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: ==============================================================================
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:  127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          14 l    5   64   37    0.000    0.000   0.031
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: LAN NTP       NTP REFERENCE IP    2 u   53   64   17    0.878  6538755 355.656
--
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: ==============================================================================
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:  127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          14 l    4   64   37    0.000    0.000   0.031
Jan  1 00:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: LAN NTP       NTP REFERENCE IP    2 u   58   64   17    0.908  6538759 459.008
--
Sep 20 06:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
Sep 20 06:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: ==============================================================================
Sep 20 06:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:  127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          14 l    -   64    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
Sep 20 06:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: *LAN NTP       NTP REFERENCE IP    2 u   33   64    1    0.634  160.235 123.523
--
Sep 20 07:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user:      remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
Sep 20 07:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: ==============================================================================
Sep 20 07:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: *127.127.1.0     .LOCL.          14 l   51   64  377    0.000    0.000   0.031
Sep 20 07:05:01 ember4 user.notice  user: LAN NTP       NTP REFERENCE IP    2 u   34   64    1    0.532  3005.52 2389.98
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt this will ever be of relevance to anyone but on the off-chance that it may save a *lot* of time invested into a fairly niche topic here's what I uncovered at the end of this rabbit hole.

So I wound up having to read though the the NTPv4 [RFC5905](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5905) and the [ntp.org source code](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/%7Entp/ntp_spool/ntp4/ntp-4.2/) to find an answer for this.

Every time a packet is processed by NTP it's evaluated against 7 tests to decide whether or not to accept or discard this packet. This all happens in the process_packet function within ntpd.c If the packet fails *any* of the 7 tests (or is not received at all) then the NTP transaction is considered a failure for the purposes of the reach metric.

The tests are as follows:

1. Does the transmit timestamp received from the NTP Server match the same transmit timestamp received from the previous packet?
2. Does the originate timestamp match the last one sent by the same peer? This is to ensure packets are not received out of order.
3. Are both the originate and receive timestamps non-zero?
4. Is the calculated delay of this packet within acceptable bounds? Essentially, if a response to an NTP request from a client takes too long to be received from the server, discard this packet.
5. If authentication is enabled for NTP, is the authenticator present and correct to decrypt packets received from this server?
6. Is the reference NTP server currently synchronized with *its* reference NTP server?
7. Is the stratum value of this reference NTP server lower than the NTP client's own stratum value?
8. Is the individual packet's root delay and root dispersion lower than established bounds? Part of this can be adjusted with the TOS MAXDIST *n* in /etc/ntp.conf to allow for higher (or lower) root dispersion from a given packet.

In my particular case, after a packet capture it was discovered that packets were failing both test 6 and test 8. Sometimes the root dispersion value being received from my NTP client's reference NTP server was several seconds or more. Default maxdist settings in NTPv4 allow for ~1.5s for the calculation: `1/2root_delay + root_dispersion` In addition the reference NTP server itself was frequently failing to sync with its own reference server.

As of this writing its still unknown what is causing sync failures with the reference server and, since I do not administer it, I've had to develop a few workarounds. Namely adding `TOS MAXDIST 60` to my NTP clients. This increased sync rate to ~90% which was determined good enough for our purposes.